# In win32 programming, why can't I see the video in Media Player if I overlay a transparent window (via WS_EX_LAYERED) over it?

Tags: windows, winapi

I've written an application that overlays a transparent window over the screen. The transparent window is created by applying `WS_EX_LAYERED` style to it, and calling `SetLayeredWindowAttributes(
            hWnd,
            RGB(0,0,255),
            127,
            LWA_ALPHA
        );`

I just run into a problem that when this transparent window is over Media Player that plays a video, the transparent region simply becomes gray and I can't see through it.

Why is that? And what can I possibly do to see the contents of Media Player through the transparent window?

Comment: Overlays often use color-keying, and your semi-transparent window is changing the color, which breaks the color key.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the following but it is what I believe it may be based on my knowledge.

Usually an overlay surface is created in the rectangle area that plays the video for hardware acceleration purposes and video card controls it (well... an application thru some api like directx controls it)

The overlay surface is draw over, let's call it, the gdi/window surface that usually is painted in black by the application.

And that's why you see the black/grey in the background.